# React to a LocalNotification when device is locked

Tags: xcode, audio, notifications, playback, lockscreen

I'm trying to start playing an alarm-sound when the app isn't closed but with locked device. The sound should start playing when a LocalNotification is fired.

I've seen this function in the "Alarm Clock" app. When the alarm begins and the device is locked, no LocalNotification is shown on the Lockscreen, but the device is start playing a sound.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I've looked for this for months now. Please let me know if you solve it. Check out [my thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725192/how-do-i-start-playing-audio-when-in-silent-mode-locked-in-ios-5-1) on this.